# how to send changing value under a "hidden" tag on a form

Tags: php, html, forms, hidden

I have 9 pictures on each page, and when someone clicks on a picture the picture is opened in a fancybox, then if a person wants more information about the piece the click on a link inside the fancybox and the form opens inside a modal box.

All of the code works and the form is send through ajax then php.

---

The problem that I have is that all 9 pictures open the same form and when I client fills out the request form with their contact information, there is no way of me knowing which photo they are looking at.

It would be nice to add a "Hidden" value that is sent with the form so I can know which photo they are requesting the information.

I have looked around SO but to no avail

---

basic form

```
  <div id="inline">

<form id="contact" name="contact" action="sendmessage.php" method="post">

    <label for="name">Your Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="msg">Enter a Message</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>




    <button id="send">Send Request</button>
</form>
```

---

link to photo

```
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="inventory/inv_pictures/pic4.jpg"><img    
     src="inventory/inv_thumbs/thumb4.jpg" alt="Antique Furniture - Pic 4"  
    id="gallery"/></a>
```

I figured that maybe there is away to add a title tag or use the alt tag under the  tag
that the form can pick up and send it as a "hidden" item. That way each photo can still access the same form but then I can know which item they are requesting for.

---

Sorry for not posting the whole code for fancy box.

but here it is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">     </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css"    media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a class="modalbox" href= "#inline"  >Request more       information</a> ' + this.title;
  },
   helpers : {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
       }
   }
});
</script>

<!-- Hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">

<form id="contact" name="contact" action="sendmessage.php" method="post">

    <label for="name">Your Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="msg">Enter a Message</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="link" name="link" value="">



    <button id="send">Send Request</button>
</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\   [[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


    $("#send").on("click", function(){
        var nameval   = $("#name").val();

        var emailval  = $("#email").val();
        var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

        var namelen   = nameval.length;

        if(namelen < 2) {
            $("#name").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(namelen >= 2) {
            $("#name").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(msglen < 4) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(msglen >= 4){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4 && namelen >= 2) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");



            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast",     function(){
                            $(this).before("<p>     <strong>Success! Your request has been sent. We will respond to it as soon as possible.   </strong></p>");                          
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 3000);     

                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the link you are giving to fancybox is a direct link to a picture.
I am confused how you get a link to the form inside the modal as it doesn't seem to be coded here.

What I would suggest is, instead of giving direct picture link, create another page and code that page to collect a pic url/id from by GET/POST and display the corresponding pic and then embed this page into the fancybox.

So basically what I am saying is, pass the pic id/path from url that you pass to the fancybox, collect it and then further pass it to the form link

Comment: The way that I have it done right now is that the customers look at a page with 9 thumbnails then when they click a thumbnail it opens the large version on a fancybox, then the form on a modal.